# You can evade the "What have you tried?" filter on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, filtering

With an extra whitespace like this:

```
What have  you tried?
```

Extra whitespace gets stripped in comments. I know, no big deal, but I figured that I should atleast mention it.

smite away

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: @nicael this applies to the main site(stackoverflow.com). there's no filter here.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you can evade the filter by simply prepending the comment with junk too: "Derp what have you tried?".

Comment: I don't think it's worth fixing. If someone wants to say "what have you tried" there's a million other ways to get around the filter. I've always regarded the block as more of a way to stop people who slapped it more or less automatically on any question without code before even reading the post.

Comment: [what have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594364/c-sharp-regex-table-header-to-italices-depending-on-a-keyword#comment38103689_24594364) - Relevant: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: The filter was put in place as an attempt to force people to actually provide some meat to the comment in order to provide some guidance.  Just asking "what have you tried" doesn't really help the OP much.  It is insanely easy to get around by adding a couple of words or spaces, so I don't think there is going to be a good solution here.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understood your question correctly. Would you mind showing us anything you have tried thus far?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help. (That is a comment I could, at last check less than a month ago, make on SO.  It is not the comment or link itself that is screened, but the 'totality' of just the comment &/or link.)

Comment: I think the filter needs to go.  It hasn't actually forced people to improve comments-  instead people just downvote or ignore rather than try to guide questioners.  What needed to be killed was multiple people commenting with this to the same question, and it seems there's better ways to do that.

Comment: `if((/[Ww][Hh][Aa][Tt][\s]{0,}[Hh][Aa][Vv][Ee][\s]{0,}[Yy][Oo][Uu][\s]{0,}[Tt][Rr][Ii][Ee][Dd][\s]{0,}[?!.]{0,}/).test(comment) == true){/* What have you tried? */}` - A javascript solution to stop that, right?

Answer (score 10):

Remember, the reason this was finally blocked was an epidemic of [very lazy people posting these comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) - to the point where folks weren't even bothering to read *other comments on the question first*, much less read the actual question itself.

I'm not gonna play some cat and mouse game with folks who really, truly, absolutely must ask - heck, I built the detection rules weak intentionally, to avoid penalizing well-meaning folks who just happened to use a common phrase.

That said, if it starts to get *really, really annoying* again...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to outright nuke these sorts of comments with a comment flag.  <s>I believe it's the "obsolete" flag, but the "not constructive" flag may work as well.</s>  Just tried it with the "not constructive flag, and yes, it is removed.

Truth be told, I've noticed these popping up and I've just flagged them instead.  It's simple enough to do, and while the filter may be a bit weak in certain spots, I definitely know that we can [remove such comments with a single comment flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/175248).

Comment: Sounds like you "closed the case".

Comment: ___Case Closed!___