# Is this comment asking for code fine?

Tags: discussion, comments, code-of-conduct, unfriendly-or-unkind, specific-comment

I'm wondering if this comment is fine:

> post code/Code's you have tried...

It was the first comment on the question, IIRC, but many more *better* comments were posted later. Context: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931431/how-to-get-a-link-to-all-the-photos-of-a-website-through-its-address) is the question.

I'd ask this somewhere else, maybe on a morals.stackexchange.com, but is this 'OK'?

Wouldn't it be more polite to say something like "Please post your code/what you've tried" by adding a small word - 'please'?

I flagged it as "It's unfriendly or unkind", as "This comment is rude or condescending. Learn more in our Code of Conduct".

Should I have reported that comment? If not as unfriendly or unkind, what else would've been a better option?

Comment: I don't think that comment is rude or condescending at all. It could be phrased better, certainly. It can be flagged as No longer needed.

Comment: Note that "polite" !== "welcoming" and vice versa. We are also not a language police - flagging comments lacking superfiical politeness as UU is exactly the kind of overzealous enforcement of CoC that SE tried to impose during the latest debacle - thankfully, even *they* realised this is too much. That said, it's not the best-worded comment, and the one following it is much closer to what is considered acceptable - flag NLN and move on.

Comment: It should be removed if only due to the unnecessary apostrophe and capitalization. "Code's". Who's Code and what of theirs should I post?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it might be a misspelling of Cody's, seems to check out :)

Comment: Give the benefit of the doubt to the commenter and assume they trying to be helpful but are struggling with English.

Comment: With or without "please" it is still a demand, especially in infinitive form. Perhaps *"May you consider, at your earliest convenience, to post your code/what you've tried?"*

Comment: "Is this acceptable" is such an open-ended question. The answer is always going to range from yes, no, don't care, maybe, donkey and what was last night's lottery number? You don't gain anything by asking about it, besides getting all the possible replies in the world and being none the wiser. I'm Dutch, according to Youtube videos about Americans moving to the Netherlands that makes me "direct". I think such a comment is... fine from a language perspective. Crude, but fine. To the point, no fluff. Not too sure if it really adds any value though, I'd have to see it in context.

Comment: @cigien, I edited this question to `Clarify meaning without changing it
Add related resources or links
Always respect the author’s intent`. I'd ask another question - "*unnecessary* link to the post; *clearer* title"?

Comment: The link is unnecessary, the question is fully understandable without the context. The edit did make the title clearer. What's not to understand?

Comment: @Nick, users like Gimby may want the context. I disagree that it's *fully* understandable without context. So, the edit removed a *necessary* link and changed "fine" to "acceptable"; the latter seems more *mediocre*. I hence disagree with that too. How's my edit not better than the previous, at least?

Comment: *"I disagree that it's fully understandable without context."* - The context was provided in your question, "here's a comment" is all the context needed to understand to show us, yes, you've found a bad comment, flag it. So the link was definitely not necessary. *""changed "fine" to "acceptable"; the latter seems more mediocre"* - Then you didn't even _look_ at the edit. It changed the title from *"Is this comment fine?"* to *"Is this comment asking for code acceptable?"*, the addition of "asking for code" was a _clear_ improvement, as it provides context from outside the question.

Comment: While changing "fine" to "acceptable" was just an improvement made at the same time. On its own it wouldn't be worth anything, but it was an opportunistic improvement seeing as the post was being edited already _anyway_.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Yeah, there's no real difference between "fine" and "acceptable" here, but my edit was to remove the link and clarify the question in the title. (The rationale for my edits has been mostly covered by Nick.) In particular, linking to posts invites the meta effect, and indeed the post has received several downvotes since being linked from here. The OP of the post did nothing to deserve this added attention, and I'm generally inclined to remove such links unless they're absolutely necessary to understand the meta question, and I don't think the link is necessary at all here.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I'm a person, not a user :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be more polite

No, it would not. Adding superficial politeness does not make something more (or less) acceptable. I also need to mention that lacking superficial (aka insincere) politeness is not the same as being "unfriendly or unkind" and, especially, *rude* or *condescending*. Let's take a look at what the latter terms mean (using Cambridge dictionary as the source - [here](http://the%20quality%20of%20being%20offensive%20or%20not%20polite) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condescension) respectively):

> behaviour that shows you think you are more important or more intelligent than other people

> the quality of being offensive or not polite

The "post ... you have tried" phrase is a simple directive [illocutionary act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocutionary_act) that is designed to compel the recipient to edit their post to include their attempt, nothing more. It does not attempt to convey intellectual superiority (the phrase does not contain any assessment of the recipient's competency, upbringing, etc) or offend the recipient (it is a simple directive). And, as mentioned earlier, lack of "polite" words does not *automatically* something less polite.

> Should I have reported that comment?

Yes, you should have, however, as "No longer needed". Such comments are mostly noise if not accompanied with links to the Help Center and guidance on providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We do not *really* need to see botched attempts of the poster trying to brute-force their way around the problem, we want them to help *us* help them.

There is even an [automatic ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251309/11407695) placed on posting "what have you tried" comments, but the check is *very* strict, so it [allows variations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262737/11407695) to be posted (such as the one you noticed). If you want to get a larger picture behind this decision or the consensus on what to do with such comments, see the following famous MSE discussion: ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172758/786798).

Answer (score 0):

This comment is not needed, please flag it as no longer needed and a mod will remove it soon.

If more clarification is needed then a comment should be clearly stating what clarity is needed.